# Why Xcode 5 Library search path fail to detect the .a lib with prefix "lib"?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

After building my app from Xcode 5, it fails to detect my library named **libLobiRecSDK.a**, with the output:

[image: error message]

But if I rename that library to **LobiRecSDK.a** without "lib" prefix, it works. It also happens with other .a library with "lib" prefix.

This is my setup for Build Settings->Library Search Paths:

[image: library search paths]

And this is how I put the library inside the project:

[image: library directory]

I put "LobiRecSDK" folder inside the xcodeproject(inside the root folder)

Comment: It looks like Xcode thinks the library is called `-lLobRecSDK` so you have mis-specified it.  Please show how you are configuring Xcode.

Comment: @trojanfoe No... Using the -l switch, the linker will look for a library with the lib prefix...

Comment: @Macmade Thanks, I know that, however I think the OP is mis-specifying this in Xcode.

Comment: OK, so show where you tell Xcode to link against the library.

Comment: Yes, i didn't point the search path to the library libLobiRecSDK.a reside. But my question still stands, why if i remove "lib" prefix, it is doing fine?

Comment: From what you've posted it looks like build fails because `libLobiResSDK.a` is not in the library search path in the first place – I believe it should be `$(SRCROOT)/lib`. As for why it doesn't fail if you rename the library that's hard to tell without seeing how exactly you're telling Xcode to link to this lib. So I concur with @trojanfoe – show how you're telling Xcode to link to the lib.

Comment: @Andrey: yes solution is `$(SRCROOT)/LobiRecSDK/lib/`, and how did I link the library? I just dragged the libLobiRecSDK.a into the Build Phase->Link Binary With Binaries. When I rename the file, I believe it still links to the same file.